# Prevent to close parent window if child windows are active

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am developing multiple instance WPF application.  Application has a grid in a main screen and on double click of grid row, it opens child window. It has also functionality to open multiple child windows on double click of grid row from main screen.

Can anybody help me to prevent parent window to be close if child windows are active? So user can not able to close main window if child windows are active.

Comment: You can use ShowDialog() to open the child window.

Comment: I can't use ShowDialog(). Because If I use it, I am not able to open multiple window and my application has functionality to open multiple windows from main(Parent) screen.

Answer (score 4):

Set Owner property for those childs to Main Windows:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var wnd = new Window();
    wnd.Owner = this;
    wnd.Show();
}
```

Then in Main Window closing event handler:

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.OwnedWindows.Count > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Child windows exists, you have to close'em first");
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

As a final point it could be helpful for you to know that you can get from anywhere in your code the app main windows with this:

```
System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow
```

So if you are using MVVM the above will help you in setting the Owner property.

Comment: If I set owner property of child window, I am unable to interact with parent window.

Comment: @DharmeshParekh Why not? Setting the Owner does not block the UI. Note that I used Show() not ShowDialog(). Review your code, probably you are using the last.

Comment: I also used show(). My issue is I can't able to interact with parent when I open Parent window from task bar if child window is active on screen. I can interact with Parent if I minimize all the child windows.

Comment: That's different issue. It has to do with the way you are creating/manipulating your instances. I suggest you to accept the answer as your original issue was solved and then open a new one properly describing your problem and posting the relevant code to gain attention from the rest of the public.

Comment: You solution does not work in my case. So I can not accept this solution as correct answer. Let me know if you can help me to solve above issue. I will accept your answer if my issue get resolved.

Comment: Then your Q is not properly redacted, I have addressed what you stated. Take your time to edit to make it more clear and explicit.

Comment: Thank you man it worked like a charm, I was showing the dialog from inside a Task and apparently it wasn't locked to the main form until I set the Owner before ShowDialog inside my Task!

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1- You can use ShowDialog() to open the child window, but user can't interact with the parent window till the child is closed.

2- You can check all windows that are currently opened by checking

```
Application.Current.Windows
```

and then you can determine whether you want to close your window or not

**Edit:**

add the following event handler to your `Parent.Closing` event

```
 private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var item  in Application.Current.Windows)
            {
                Window window = item as Window;
                if (window.Title == "YourChildWindowTitle")
                  {

                         // show some message for user to close childWindows

                        e.Cancel = true;
                         break;

                  }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I need to interact with parent window when child windows are open and need to open multiple child windows from parent. So I can't use ShowDialog(). Can you please give me more details about 2nd point. How can I use it?

Comment: How can I determine child windows are open or not?

Comment: this property Application.Current.Windows will give all windows that are instantiated in your app, then you can search by it's name

Answer (score 0):

In window closing command pass that if the child window is open disable closing functionality.

**Or**

you what you can do is make `canexecute = false` when a pop up is open and closing command is triggered.

Comment: How can I determine child windows are open or not?

Comment: use if condition to determine that if your child window with that ID or Name is active or visible better bind visibility property and then check using that.

Comment: or you can disable close button when you open first child window and re-enable it when the last child window is destroyed.

Comment: But In my case all the child windows will be open from a parent window. I can't determine which window is closed.

Comment: see create a collection and store the count of it or may be names and increment and decrement according to open and destruction of your windows.

Answer (score 0):

Attach a function to the main window's 'Closing' event, and check to see if the child window is open. if it is, set

```
e.cancel = true;
```

Comment: How can I determine child windows are open or not?

Comment: steve he cant use events he is following MVVM pattern and he has to use command behviors to achieve.

Comment: dharmesh you must be having a child window name or ID then with that check if it is active or visible.